# drag and drop in GTK for C

Tags: c, gtk

I need help coding a drag and drop operation for images/pixbuf in a program that I'm coding and I would love a guide on how to do so\ a code that executes and handles the drag and drop operation

I have tried looking for guides online and on youtube and even tried using chatgpt but nothing helped me in solving the issue

I am using windows 10 (64bits)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: Found this:  https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/drag-and-drop.html